# Protocol extensions not using most specific implementation

Tags: swift, generics

I have two classes, `Object` and `SubObject`. A protocol, `MyProtocol`, has an `associatedtype` of type `Object`. In two extensions, I have provided implementations of the `save` function. When I create an instance of `TestClass` with either of the classes, they both result in a call to the least specific extension implementation, while it would be expected to call the most specific one.

```
class Object {}
class SubObject: Object {}

protocol MyProtocol {
    associatedtype T: Object
    func save()
}

extension MyProtocol {
    func save() {
        print("Object")
    }
}

extension MyProtocol where T == SubObject {
    func save() {
        print("SubObject")
    }
}

class MyClass<T: Object>: MyProtocol {
}

class TestClass<T: Object> {
    typealias U = MyClass<T>

    func test() {
        let myClass = U()
        myClass.save()
    }
}

let testClass1 = TestClass<Object>()
testClass1.test() // returns "Object"

let testClass2 = TestClass<SubObject>()
testClass2.test() // returns "Object" (should be "SubObject")
```

How can I solve this, so that the `TestClass` calls the correct implementation of `save`? Or is this not currently possible in Swift? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: declare your method in the superclass and override it in your subclass

Comment: @LeoDabus What do you mean? In what class should I define the `save` method?

Comment: In your Object class

Comment: I don't have too much experience with associated types, it is just a guess

Comment: @LeoDabus Ah okay, that would definitely be a possibility! But I would prefer to not put `save` in `Object`, if possible